# How to stop WordPress from changing ellipsis into a pre-composed triple-dot glyph?

Tags: filters, characters

When I type an ellipsis composed of three separate dots `...`, WordPress displays the pre-composed triple-dot glyph `…` instead.

Is there any way to prevent WordPress from substitution the three dots?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Where do you need three dots?

Comment: Just out of personal preference... There are also several style guides that recommend `...` instead of `…` The ellipsis character did not exist before the advent of computers and in my humble opinion should not be used outside of a few specific use cases.

Comment: How wide an ellipsis is depends on the font. Semantically it is _one_ character, hence the separate Unicode code point `U+2026`. It is also easier for automatic translation tools and screen readers if you use the special character.

Answer (score 2):

Three dots are converted to the typographically correct ellipsis … in `wptexturize()`. You can disable it in many cases, see my [plugin Disable Wptexturize](https://gist.github.com/982554).

Answer (score 2):

That conversion - among others - is caused by the [`wptexturize()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wptexturize) filter being applied to [`the_content()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content).

The sledge-hammer approach to preventing `wp_texturize()` being applied to `the_content()` is simply to *remove the filter*, like so:

```
<?php
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wptexturize' );
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the plugin wp-Typography, which can override WordPress's native character replacements. If you **disable** the changes you don't want in the plugin, they won't show up in the front-end anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of removing the entire `wptexturize` filter, I think a better approach to this issue is to let `wptexturize()` run and then undo the replaced ellipsis glyph with the three dots.

The filter is run at a priority of 11 so that it runs after `wptexturize()`.

```
function wpse_45245_the_content( $content )
{
  return str_replace( '&#8230;', '...', $content );
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpse_45245_the_content', 11 );
```

Note that this only replaces it in `the_content` filter, if you want it replaced in `the_excerpt`, `the_title`, etc., then you'll need to add those filters as well.

Answer (score 0):

Several possibilities, based on the use of a shortcode called '...' (Yes, that's a legal shortcode name.)

- Exempt the shortcode via the `no_texturize_shortcodes` filter.
- Have the shortcode wrap the three period characters with a `<code>` tag (which is by default exempted from texturizing, so no filter is needed).
- Similar to the above, but wrap it in a `<span>`, and use CSS to have it rendered in a font with an ellipsis character whose look you prefer (would need the filter this way).